# Cannot read property 'setHash' of undefined - SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to navigate to "BadConfiguration" page some user attributes match. 
But I keep getting Cannot read property 'setHash' of undefined error. 
I tried to make few changes, then I get replaceHash error. It is just one page application and if the user is not a particular one - I have to show bad Configuration page.

EDIT: Changed to reflect router name correctly. But issue is - it works only if I put that call to navigate somewhere else. For example, if I give a button on page, on click of which I call a function inside that I give a call to navigate. 
If I don't do that and try to give that  line code to navigate in init() or initializeView() it returns with setHash error.

***Manifest.json***

```
        "routes": [
        {
      "pattern": "",
      "name": "G_Table",
      "target": "G_Table"
    },
        {
        "name": "BadConfiguration",
        "pattern": "BadConfiguration",
        "greedy": false,
        "target": "BadConfiguration"

    }],
    "targets": {
            "G_Table": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "show",
                "clearAggregation": true,
                "viewName": "G_Table",
                "viewLevel": 1,
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "app"
            },

            "BadConfiguration": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "show",
                "clearAggregation": true,
                "viewName": "BadConfiguration",
                "viewLevel": 1,
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "app"
            }

    }
}
}
```

***Component.js***

```
init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // set the device model
        this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        this.getRouter().initialize();

    }
```

There are 2 views namely -> G_Table.xml and BadConfiguration.xml

***G_Table.xml***

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Plant_Data_Plant_Data.controller.G_Table"
     xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
    <App id="app">
        <pages>
        <Page title="Plants" showHeader="true">
```

***G_Table.controller.js***

```
return Controller.extend("Plant_Data_Plant_Data.controller.G_Table", {
        onInit: function() {
        var userModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("/services/userapi/currentUser");
        this.getView().setModel(userModel, "userapi");

 // here the aim is if some properties satisfy, then route to bad 
   configuration

  if(true)
 {
 this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("bc", {}, false);

 //I get setHash undefined error here
  }
  this.initializeView();
    },


    initializeView: function() {

        this.populateTable();

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the router name when trying to navigate to a page. The issue here is, you are trying to navigate to a page giving its target name.

You must try,

> this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("BadConfiguration" ..... );

An example to refer to how routing works: [Routing and Navigation in SAPUI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.9/docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html)
Additionally, I don't think you would need the pattern in this case if you know when to call this view.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you, when I change it to router name it works. But it works only if I put that call to navigate somewhere else. For example, if I give a button on page, on click of which I call a function inside that I give a call to navigate. 
If I don't do that and try to give that  line code to navigate in init() or initializeView() it returns with setHash error.

Comment: What does this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter()  return.?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the nav inside the onInit.

The onInit event should be used to initialize properties regarding its controller. At the point the onInit is fired, the other views and other controllers are not yet "know" to SAPUI5.

On the onInit event, register a routeMatched event and then on routeMatched do the navigation.

Like this:

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller'],
    function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    var that;

    return Controller.extend("sapui5Example.home", {



                 onInit: function () {

                that = this;
                 sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(that).getRoute('rtHome').attachPatternMatched(
                    onRouteOrSubRoutesMatched);
            }





    });

      function onRouteOrSubRoutesMatched() {

        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(that).navTo('yourOtherRoute');

        }


});
```

Here is a plunker: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/YjGzWe/